# Event calendar for outlook

Tags: php, curl, icalendar, php-curl

I have creating **iCal** feature for event calendar
Received mail with .ics file but not set Calendar event
please see .ics file code below

I have tried sent mail by Curl but not created RSVP only received .ics file

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Access-A-Ride Pickup
ORGANIZER:info@example.com
ATTENDEE:example@outlook.com
LAST-MODIFIED:20221013T100253
UID:20221013T1313001620512614@example.com
DTSTAMP:20221013T100253
DTSTART:20221013T131300
DTEND:20221013T141300
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SUMMARY:Test Repair Soft
LOCATION:365888
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:1
PRIORITY:3
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";


        
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"personalizations\": [{\"to\": [{\"email\": \"".$to_address."\"}]}],\"from\": {\"email\": \"".$from_address."\",\"name\": \"".$from_name."\"},\"subject\": \"".$subject."\",\"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/calendar\", \"value\": \"".$ical."\"}]}");

        $headers = array();
        
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer Auth Token Key';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            // echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        } else {
            // echo "Message has been sent.";
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

---

Received Now, this file in my mail
[image: Received mail now]

But i need This type of mail by CURL code
[image: I need this type of mail]

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working? Is this a cURL problem?

Comment: When we sent mail by curl with event ical then have only received .ics file but was not create calendar event by curl mail in outlook, but i need to create calendar event automatic by this code, when we use mail() then will possible but i need to create by curl only

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Maybe the API you use does not support adding attachments to a mail?

Comment: \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/calendar\", \"value\": \"".$message_news."\"}]
When we add this content in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS therefore sent mail with one attachments, attachments file (invite.ics) created automatic with above $ical content by text/calendar

when received this file then should auto create calendar event by this code but not able to create event in the calendar

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If the mail contains an attachment, but that itself is not working as expected, did you check how that attachment differs from one you create directly using Outlook?

Comment: Yes, When we sent this invite.ics file by gmail to outlook then will working perfect but when we sent .ics file by curl mail then will receive only for file please see screenshot in my question, i have edited

Comment: If you check the markup of both mails, what's the difference?